# syntax error :PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php

i am trying this time sending email with attachment code seems correct without sending email with attachment. but i got error as PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file on line 77 what is missing ???

```
    <?php
           if(isset($_FILES) && (bool) $_FILES) {
        $AllowedExtensions = ["pdf","doc","docx","gif","jpeg","jpg","png","rtf","txt"];
        $files = [];
        $server_file = [];
        foreach($_FILES as $name => $file) {
            $file_name = $file["name"];
            $file_temp = $file["tmp_name"];
            foreach($file_name as $key) {
                $path_parts = pathinfo($key);
                $extension = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
                if(!in_array($extension, $AllowedExtensions)) { die("Extension not allowed"); }
                $server_file[] = "uploads/{$path_parts["basename"]}";
            }
            for($i = 0; $i<count($file_temp); $i++) { move_uploaded_file($file_temp[$i], $server_file[$i]); }
        }
        $headers = "From: $from";
        $semi_rand = md5(time());
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
        $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
        $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        $FfilenameCount = 0;
        for($i = 0; $i<count($server_file); $i++) {
            $afile = fopen($server_file[$i],"rb");
            $data = fread($afile,filesize($server_file[$i]));
            fclose($afile);
            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
            $name = $file_name[$i];
            $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$name\"\n" .
                "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$name\"\n" .
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
            $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        }

if($_POST['submit'] !='')
{
$name = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['name']);

$email = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['email']);

$mobile = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['mobile']);

$company = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['company']);

$qty = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['qty']);

//$upload = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['upload']);

$msg = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['msg']);

}

$to="example@gmail.com";


$subject = "Order Information";

$message .= "Name: " . $name . "\n";

$message .= "Email: " . $email . "\n";

$message .= "ContactNo: " . $mobile . "\n";

$message .= "Company: " . $company . "\n";

$message .= "Quantity: " . $qty . "\n";

//$message .= "Upoload: " . $upload . "\n";

$message .= "Message: " . $msg . "\n";


if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{   echo 'thank you';   }
else{ echo 'error';}
?>
```

Comment: There is a } missing at tge end of the file

Comment: you dint close the if (isset) condition

Comment: simple error reporting could have told you.

Comment: Depends in your logic. I think you should add it to the last line

Comment: i have added } at line no 77 but get the email only with uploaded image it does not receiving other information also after downloading image it and opening it shows windows can't view this in picture view because file is empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES) && (bool) $_FILES) {
        $AllowedExtensions = ["pdf","doc","docx","gif","jpeg","jpg","png","rtf","txt"];
        $files = [];
        $server_file = [];
        foreach($_FILES as $name => $file) {
            $file_name = $file["name"];
            $file_temp = $file["tmp_name"];
            foreach($file_name as $key) {
                $path_parts = pathinfo($key);
                $extension = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
                if(!in_array($extension, $AllowedExtensions)) { die("Extension not allowed"); }
                $server_file[] = "uploads/{$path_parts["basename"]}";
            }
            for($i = 0; $i<count($file_temp); $i++) { move_uploaded_file($file_temp[$i], $server_file[$i]); }
        }
        $headers = "From: $from";
        $semi_rand = md5(time());
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
        $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
        $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        $FfilenameCount = 0;
        for($i = 0; $i<count($server_file); $i++) {
            $afile = fopen($server_file[$i],"rb");
            $data = fread($afile,filesize($server_file[$i]));
            fclose($afile);
            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
            $name = $file_name[$i];
            $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$name\"\n" .
                "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$name\"\n" .
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
            $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        }

if($_POST['submit'] !='')
{
$name = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['name']);

$email = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['email']);

$mobile = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['mobile']);

$company = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['company']);

$qty = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['qty']);

//$upload = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['upload']);

$msg = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['msg']);

}

$to="amar.ghodke30@gmail.com";


$subject = "Order Information";

$message .= "Name: " . $name . "\n";

$message .= "Email: " . $email . "\n";

$message .= "ContactNo: " . $mobile . "\n";

$message .= "Company: " . $company . "\n";

$message .= "Quantity: " . $qty . "\n";

//$message .= "Upoload: " . $upload . "\n";

$message .= "Message: " . $msg . "\n";


if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{   echo 'thank you';   }
else{ echo 'error';}
    } // This one is missing :)
?>
```

You had a missing "}" at the end of the file.

Comment: this will return undefined index notices.. see my update

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `Syntax error, unexpected end` because you missed the ending bracket for this line:

```
if(isset($_FILES) && (bool) $_FILES) {
```

Also note that, when you fix this parse error, you will the few **Undefined Indexes Notices** because you defined `$name, $email` etc inside the `if($_POST['submit'] !='')` and using outside the check.

**Full Modified Code:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES) && (bool) $_FILES) {
    $AllowedExtensions = ["pdf","doc","docx","gif","jpeg","jpg","png","rtf","txt"];
    $files = [];
    $server_file = [];
    foreach($_FILES as $name => $file) {
        $file_name = $file["name"];
        $file_temp = $file["tmp_name"];
        foreach($file_name as $key) {
            $path_parts = pathinfo($key);
            $extension = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
            if(!in_array($extension, $AllowedExtensions)) { die("Extension not allowed"); }
            $server_file[] = "uploads/{$path_parts["basename"]}";
        }
        for($i = 0; $i<count($file_temp); $i++) { move_uploaded_file($file_temp[$i], $server_file[$i]); }
    }
    $headers = "From: $from";
    $semi_rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    $FfilenameCount = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i<count($server_file); $i++) {
        $afile = fopen($server_file[$i],"rb");
        $data = fread($afile,filesize($server_file[$i]));
        fclose($afile);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $name = $file_name[$i];
        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$name\"\n" .
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$name\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    }
}

/** Your submit block **/
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['name']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['email']);
    $mobile = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['mobile']);
    $company = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['company']);
    $qty = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['qty']);
    $msg = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['msg']);
    $to="example@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Order Information";
    $message .= "Name: " . $name . "\n";
    $message .= "Email: " . $email . "\n";
    $message .= "ContactNo: " . $mobile . "\n";
    $message .= "Company: " . $company . "\n";
    $message .= "Quantity: " . $qty . "\n";
    $message .= "Message: " . $msg . "\n";
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {   
        echo 'thank you';   
    }
    else { 
        echo 'error';
    }
}

?>
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I don't know why are you using `$message` at end of this line:

```
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
```

It will also give you Undefined Variable Notice, just remove it.

Comment: i have added it to line no 77 after mail function ends...

Comment: after this fix, you will get the undefined index notices.. @GOVINDAMAHAJAN

Comment: got this messages ...

Comment: Warning:move_uploaded_file(uploads/order.jpg):failed to open stream:No such file or directory on line 15 Warning:move_uploaded_file():Unable to move '/tmp/phpoJARVm' to'uploads/order.jpg' on line 15 Notice:Undefined variable:on line17 Notice:Undefined variable: message on line 21 Warning:fopen(uploads/order.jpg):failed to open stream: No such file or directory on line 25  Warning:filesize():stat failed for uploads/order.jpg on line 26 Warning:fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given on line 26 Warning:fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource,boolean given on line 27

Comment: @GOVINDAMAHAJAN: check your file path, this is another issue.. not related to this question.

Comment: thank you sir, i have added this code as it is in my mail.php this works but now this only shows attachment not all form filed values.. what can i do for this ???

Comment: i suggest u to create a separate question u will get more exposure. @GOVINDAMAHAJAN

Comment: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: from  on line 17
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: message  on line 21

Comment: @GOVINDAMAHAJAN: which one is line 21?

Comment: line 17  $headers = "From: $from";                                                           line 21 $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";

Comment: see friend, "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n" here $message is not defined.. @GOVINDAMAHAJAN

Comment: just use this: $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n"; @GOVINDAMAHAJAN

Comment: @GOVINDAMAHAJAN: i have also updated in answer.

Comment: what about line 17 $headers = "From: $from";                                        PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: from on line 17

Comment: @GOVINDAMAHAJAN: $from = "youremail@test.com";
    $headers = "From: $from";

Comment: i have updated there are no errors but i got only attachment not all input values...

Comment: @GOVINDAMAHAJAN: this is another, issue, attachment and html in email body, i suggest u to create a new question... like HOW to get HTML and Attachment in email together ...

Comment: thank you for your kind and deep suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

Missing one closing bracket before this line...

```
if($_POST['submit'] !='')
```

You have not closed your first if condition block.

Comment: this will solve parse error only, check my solution, OP have two issues.